# Save CSV as local file with Expo File System

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-file-system

I am using supabase as my storage, and i am making a request to get the response as CSV, as follows:

```
const exportColetasAsCSV = async ( IDs: number[] ) => {
const {data, error} = await supabase
    .from('coletas')
    .select()
    .in('id', IDs)
    .csv();

if (error) console.log('Erro exportColetasAsCSV:', error);
return data;
}
```

And i want to share it using expo-sharing (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sharing/), but to do that i need to have it as a local file, so i'm trying to save it locally with File-System (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/), but to save it locally i only see examples using http uri, like this:

```
FileSystem.downloadAsync(
    'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4',
    FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'small.mp4'
  )
  .then(({ uri }) => {
    Alert.alert(
      "App",
      uri
    );
})
```

**Can i save it as a CSV like the one i receive as a response from supabase? If so, how?**

Answer (score 1):

I searched around and was able to make it work!
Here's how i made it:

```
const saveFile = async (data) => {

let directoryUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory;

let fileUri = directoryUri + "name.csv";

await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(fileUri, data, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.UTF8 });

return fileUri;
};

const shareFile = async (fileUri) => {
const canShare = await Sharing.isAvailableAsync();

// Check if permission granted
if (canShare) {
  try{
    const res = await Sharing.shareAsync(fileUri);
    console.log('shareAsync', res);
    return true;
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
} else {
  alert("Você precisa dar permissão para Compartilhar.")
}};
```

Answer (score -1):

**I found best way, no need to check file, directory as writeAsStringAsync automatically creates directory and file**

It creates csv file from JSON, using expo-sharing share or save

```
    const exportToCsv = async (list, reportType, yearOf) => {
        let formatData: any = []
        list.map(ds => {
            let obj = {}
            for (let key in ds) {
                if (key !== '_id' && key !== 'createdAt' && key !== 'updatedAt') obj[toSentenceCase(key).replace(/""/g, '')] = ds[key]
            }
            formatData.push(obj)
        })
        const CSV = jsonToCSV(formatData);
        const directoryUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory;
        const fileUri = directoryUri + `${reportType}s-${yearOf}-${moment().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')}.csv`;
        FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(fileUri, CSV)
        await shareAsync(fileUri, { UTI: '.csv', mimeType: 'application/csv' })
    }
```